# Ruby: check for nil in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

I've got a `getJSON` script that should respond if a Ruby value is not `nil`, but I'm not sure how to check for `if not (ruby's version of) nil` through javascript. So far it looks like this:

```
$.getJSON("<%= xhr_document_path(document) %>", function(d) {
    if (d.ok) {
        $('#modal_<%= document.id %>').modal('show');
        clearInterval(doc_modal_<%= document.id %>);
    } else if (d.error != '') {
        window.location.href = "<%= error_document_path(document) %>";
    }
});
```

But the `else if` condition is tripped when the value is nil. How do I check for `not nil` here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `d` was converted from Ruby to JavaScript through JSON, then the Ruby `nil` would be converted to JavaScript `null`.

Comment: THANK-YOU. I've been tearing my hair out.